# Copy Recently Modified Files with Folder Structure Using PowerShell

Tags: powershell

I'm new to PowerShell. Can someone please help me with my requirement as below.
I have Folder, subFolders, and sub-subfolders,... and files inside each level of folders.
If any file gets modified/created, I need to copy that modified/created file with the respective folder structure.

E.g., I have a folder structure like below.

```
src
├── classes
│   └── ClassFile1(file)
├── objects
│   └── ObjectFile1(file)
└── Aura
    └── Component
        ├── ComponentFile1(file)
        └── ComponentFile2(file)
```

Now if ComponentFile1 gets changed, then I need to copy folder structure only related to that file to my target folder. Like src/aura/Component/ComponentFile1.

I have tried something like this which is not working.

```
$Targetfolder= "C:\Users\Vamsy\desktop\Continuous Integration\Target"

$Sourcefolder= "C:\Users\Vamsy\desktop\Continuous Integration\Source"

$files = get-childitem $Sourcefolder -file | 
          where-object { $_.LastWriteTime -gt [datetime]::Now.AddMinutes(-5) }|
          Copy-Item -Path $files -Destination $Targetfolder -recurse -Force
```

Any Help on this appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try the code below.

```
$srcDir = "C:\Users\Vamsy\desktop\Continuous Integration\Target"
$destDir = "C:\Users\Vamsy\desktop\Continuous Integration\Source"

Get-ChildItem $srcDir -File -Recurse |
Where-Object LastWriteTime -gt (Get-Date).AddMinutes(-5) |
ForEach-Object {
    $destFile = [IO.FileInfo]$_.FullName.Replace($srcDir, $destDir)
    if($_.LastWriteTime -eq $destFile.LastWriteTime) { return }
    $destFile.Directory.Create()
    Copy-Item -LiteralPath $_.FullName -Destination $destFile.FullName -PassThru
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @rokumaru 
You made my day..!!

Answer (score 0):

What you want is easy achievable with **robocopy** instead of **copy-item**.
It has the options for sysncing folders, purging deleted folders, and many others.
Usage is something like this:

```
$source = 'C:\source-fld'
$destination = 'C:\dest-fld'
$robocopyOptions = @('/NJH', '/NJS') #just add the options you need
$fileList = 'test.txt' #optional you can provide only some files or folders or exclude some folders (good for building a project when you want only the sourcecode updated)

Start robocopy -args "$source $destination $fileList $robocopyOptions"
```

Some useful options:

**/s** -  include non-empty subdirectories
**/e** to include the all the subdirs (sometimes needed as content will be put there at build or test time)
**/b** - backup mode - copy newr files only
**/purge** - delete what was deleted in source folder

For all the parameters see [robocopy docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/robocopy)

Comment: Thanks for the reply.
I have tried with RoboCopy but in my scenario, I need the latest modified files or files modified in the last 5 minutes. Using Robocopy we can filter up to days/date but not at the minutes I believe.
So I got stuck there with RoboCopy/XCopy.